# Регулярные выражение - не заменяет символы

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, replace

нужно заменять числа|символы, стоящие одни, для этого я использую границу слова - `\b`. Почему заменяются только буквы и цифры, но заменяются символы(`№%*-.`), хотя я их экранирую?

```
str = "1 %% | 11 % | 1";
str.replace(/\b1\b/g, "_") // _ %% | 11 % | _ # все работает



str = "1 %% | 11 % | 1";
str.replace(/\b%\b/g, "_") // 1 %% | 11 % | 1 # не заменяет
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Граница слова (`\b`) - это мнимая точка между символами `\w` и `\W`.

`\w` - алфавитно-цифровой символ или символ подчеркивания, а `\W` не алфавитно-цифровой символ и не символ подчеркивания.

Символы (№%*-.) и пробел принадлежат к одной группе - `\W`. Границы слова нет!

Answer (score 1):

Потому что % не входит в набор символов, которые могут быть в "слове", границы которого задает паттерн `\b` :) 
В "слове" должны быть символы, которые определяются паттерном `\w`

Просто пробелы поставьте с двух сторон.